# Handling of two forms in one webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a webpage with a div area. In this area, there can be two different forms.
It looks like this:

Form 1:

```
<div id="data" ...>
    <form action="/action1" method="post">
        <label for="label1">ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="label1" value="" />
        <label for="label2">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="label2" value="" />
        <label for="label3">Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="label3" value="" />
        <label for="label4">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="label4" value="" />
     </form>
</div>
```

Form 2:

```
<div id="data" ...>
    <form action="/action2" method="post">
        <label for="label1">ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="label1" value="" />
        <label for="label2">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="first" id="label2" value="" />
        <label for="label3">Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" name="last" id="label3" value="" />
        <label for="label4">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="label4" value="" />
        <label for="label5">eMail</label>
        <input type="text" name="mail" id="label5" value="" />
     </form>
</div>
```

So there are two different forms. The values will be set with jQuery (Ajax call to the backend).

What is the best way to handle these two forms? Should I create two files with only the form and the load the form when they are needed? (Form 1 is needed if some clicks on button 1, form 2 is needed if someoe clicks on button 2 - the events are handled on client-side).
Or should I place both form into the single HTML file and enable or disable the form?

Comment: You can also have one form and show/hide certain elements plus change the form action using jQuery. If you stick with two forms, I second Jamie answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you have both forms in the HTML and conditionally hiding/showing the one that you want active. You're best bet is to give each form (or its containing div) a unique ID, and using this to show/hide using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep both the forms in the same page. And show/hide the required form as per the requirement.

Because if you keep the forms in separate HTML files, and user clicks on any button, then you'll have to make a `XMLHttpRequest` to get the HTML of form, whereas you can easily avoid this extra HTML request by including the HTML of the form in the same page.

I don't know if your website audience is so large or not. But saving a single `HttpRequest` should be very helpful.

See the article *[Minimize HTTP Requests by Yahoo developers](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http)*. They clearly suggest to minimize HTTP requests.